# Toolbar is showing on left of SearchView in android

Tags: android, toolbar, searchview

I want to show Back button but distorted ToolBar is coming on left as in the following image.

[image]

```
 @Override
 public void onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu, MenuInflater inflater) {
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);

    MenuItem item = menu.findItem(R.id.action_search);
    SearchView searchView = (SearchView) MenuItemCompat.getActionView(item);

    TextView tv = (TextView) searchView.findViewById(android.support.v7.appcompat.R.id.search_src_text);
    tv.setTextColor(getResources().getColor(android.R.color.white));
    tv.setHintTextColor(getResources().getColor(android.R.color.white));
    tv.setHint(getString(R.string.action_search));

    ImageView imgCloseIcon = (ImageView) searchView.findViewById(android.support.v7.appcompat.R.id.search_close_btn);
    imgCloseIcon.setImageResource(R.drawable.cross_btn);

    searchView.setOnQueryTextListener(this);
}
```

How to show Back button and hide distorted ToolBar ??

Answer (score 0):

I have used the below code and its working fine for me,

```
    SearchView searchView = (SearchView) MenuItemCompat.getActionView(menu.findItem(R.id.action_search));
    SearchManager searchManager = (SearchManager) getSystemService(SEARCH_SERVICE);
    searchView.setSearchableInfo(searchManager
            .getSearchableInfo(getComponentName()));


    searchView.setOnQueryTextListener(queryTextListener);
```